# How to convert multiple parameters URLs into single parameter URLs in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
$ cat urls.txt
http://example.com/test/test/test?apple=&bat=&cat=&dog=
https://test.com/test/test/test?aa=&bb=&cc=
http://target.com/test/test?hmm=
```

I want output like below  , how can i do that in bash ( single line command )

```
$ cat urls.txt
http://example.com/test/test/test?apple=
http://example.com/test/test/test?bat=
http://example.com/test/test/test?cat=
http://example.com/test/test/test?dog=
https://test.com/test/test/test?aa=
https://test.com/test/test/test?bb=
https://test.com/test/test/test?cc=
http://target.com/test/test?hmm=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'?|=&|=' '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1 "?" $i "="}' urls.txt 
http://example.com/test/test/test?apple=
http://example.com/test/test/test?bat=
http://example.com/test/test/test?cat=
http://example.com/test/test/test?dog=
https://test.com/test/test/test?aa=
https://test.com/test/test/test?bb=
https://test.com/test/test/test?cc=
http://target.com/test/test?hmm=
```

Answer (score 0):

I try use sed but it is complex. if use perl like this:

```
perl -pe 'if(/(.*\?)/){$url=$1;s#&#\n$url#g;}' url.txt
```

it works well.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` using `gensub()`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/^(https?:)(.*)(\?[[:alpha:]]+=)(.*)/,"\\1\\2\\3","g")}' file
http://example.com/test/test/test?apple=
https://test.com/test/test/test?aa=
http://target.com/test/test?hmm=
```

- `gensub()` for specifying components of the regexp in the replacement text, using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components (four here). We print only 3 of them: `"\\1\\2\\3"` .

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(([^?]+\?)[^=]+=)&/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace each `&` by a newline and the substring before the first parameter, print/delete the first line and repeat.